# Passing parameter as a string into dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Considering this SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @SQLString          NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQLString = '
DECLARE @CountryCode    varchar(3)
DECLARE @CountryName    varchar(60)

DECLARE AutoCursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CountryCode, 
        CountryName 
    FROM Country

OPEN AutoCursor
FETCH FROM AutoCursor INTO @CountryCode, @CountryName

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
            BEGIN TRAN

                EXEC SP_StoredProcedure_1
                    @ExtraWhereClause   = N'' AND CountryCode= ''''@CountryCode'''' '',
                    @Name               = @CountryName

            COMMIT TRAN                             
    FETCH Next FROM AutoCursor INTO @D_Nationcode, @C_Name
    END
CLOSE AutoCursor
DEALLOCATE AutoCursor;  
'
PRINT (@SQLString)
EXEC (@SQLString)
```

How can I pass `@CountryCode` as a parameter in a string?

`@ExtraWhereClause = N'' AND CountryCode= ''' + @CountryCode + ''' ''`, doesn't seem to work as `@CountryCode` is already used in dynamic SQL.

Comment: Your cursor is using 2 undeclared variables in the `FETCH NEXT` statement inside the loop.

Comment: What is the need of `dynamic Sql` here

Answer (score 1):

```
@ExtraWhereClause = N'' AND CountryCode= '''''' + @CountryCode+ ''''''  '',
```

Got it.... i should use more apostrophe symbols.... geez, i'm really bad in using the correct amount of apostrophe symbol =(

Comment: I just did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can do this with a simpler Dynamic Sql

```
Create table #temp (CountryCode int,
                      CountryName varchar(50))

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT CountryCode, CountryName FROM ' + @TableName 

Insert into #temp
exec sp_executesql @sql

DECLARE @CountryCode VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @CountryName VARCHAR(60)
DECLARE AutoCursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT CountryCode,
                  CountryName
  FROM   #temp

OPEN AutoCursor

FETCH FROM AutoCursor INTO @CountryCode, @CountryName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      BEGIN TRAN

      EXEC Sp_storedprocedure_1
        @ExtraWhereClause = N'',
        @CountryCode= @CountryCode,
        @Name = @CountryName

      COMMIT TRAN

      FETCH Next FROM AutoCursor INTO @CountryCode, @CountryName
  END

CLOSE AutoCursor

DEALLOCATE AutoCursor
```

Comment: but i really need to use it dynamically.... Because the actual table name is not "Country" but a parameter pass from user....   SELECT DISTINCT CountryCode,
                  CountryName
  FROM   Country

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT 
CountryCode, CountryName
  FROM ' + @TableName + '

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything here that requires dynamic sql, but if you really **really** want to you can use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)